# Alt-tab in full screen

Tags: directx-11

I'm using DX11 for a small application that mainly runs in full screen.
The problem is when I <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> the application goes to windowed mode and if I <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> back it doesn't go back to full screen.

I have seen other applications and games keeping the full-screen state after alt-tabbing, how can I keep the full-screen mode when <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your SwapChain you use IDXGIFactory object. That same object has a method called, **MakeWindowAssociation**, call that method with the following flag: **DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER**. (More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174540(v=vs.85).aspx )

It will prevent automatic changed from fullscreen to window mode.

You can also investigate this methods of **IDXGISwapChain** to see how to handle manual changes from full to window: **SetFullscreenState** (more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174540(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what you are talking about, I don't want to disable the alt-enter. 
I want to keep the full-screen state of my application when I alt-tab.
I tried what you said but when I alt-tab, in full-screen, the application goes automatically in windowed mode instead of keeping the fullscreen state.