# Windows alt + tab causes windowed mode

Tags: windows, fullscreen, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I'm using marmalade 6.2 and cocos 2.1 beta3.x.2.1. When I deploy windows build in fullscreen mode alt-tabbing out and back into the application causes the application to go to windowed mode. Is there a command / setting that needs to be set in app.icf / elsewhere to ensure the fullscreen is kept after an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

I found the post below which might be related:

[Alt-tab in full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432254/alt-tab-in-full-screen)

Thanks,

Line

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `WinAllowAltEnter` and `WinFullScreen` icf settings. I guess this is what you need, especially the `WinFullScreen`.

Also check the description of `WinFullScreen`

```
If this is set, the display will be changed to a mode governed by WinWidth, WinHeight and WindowBpp. The surface will then cover the whole of the screen. If device does not support full screen mode with resolutions specified in WinWidth and WinHeight settings, application will start in windowed mode regardless of the WinFullScreen flag with specified resolution. Default is 0.
```

So I guess what you might have done is misconfiguring the WinWidth/WinHeight settings.

Comment: Well I've had settings like: WinFullScreen=0 WinWidth=1024 WinHeight=768 WinAllowAltEnter=1 and WinFullScreen=0 WinWidth=1920 WinHeight=1080 WinAllowAltEnter=1. I have also tried not specifying a winHeight / winWidth. As soon as an alt + tab has happened the window gets borders and isn't true fullscreen, its just a large window in the resolution specified.